# XML scraping using shell

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, shell

I have the following output

```
<computers><size>5</size><computer><id>1</id><name>NSK1210050726M</name></computer><computer><id>2</id><name>nsk1200015739m</name></computer><computer><id>3</id><name>SFO1502083053M</name></computer><computer><id>5</id><name>nsk1501817326m</name></computer><computer><id>8</id><name>nsk1501901173m</name></computer></computers>
```

and I want to get only the names inside of   tags using shell scripting.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I tried using sed but it ouputs the entire list including tags

Comment: You should post the code you tried

Comment: sed -n '/<name>/p' CurlOutPut.txt | sed  's/.*(<name>)\(.*\)(\/<name>).*/\1/'

Comment: any ideas how I can complete this using scripting?

Comment: @user1582375 most Linux and Unix distros come with command line XPath tools. I think you should look for one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your xml is in a shell variable, say `$XML` then you can use shell parameter substitution and a simple loop to do a really bad job of parsing it.

```
XML='<computers><size>5</size><computer><id>1</id><name>NSK1210050726M</name></computer><computer><id>2</id><name>nsk1200015739m</name></computer><computer><id>3</id><name>SFO1502083053M</name></computer><computer><id>5</id><name>nsk1501817326m</name></computer><computer><id>8</id><name>nsk1501901173m</name></computer></computers>'
match=0
for word in ${XML//[<>]/ }; do
    if [ $match -eq 1 ]; then
        echo $word
        match=0
    elif [ $word = "name" ]; then
        match=1
    fi
done
```

But really, REALLY, using something like xml starlet suggested by @Brian Agnew is a much better idea.

Comment: The "magic" is the parameter expansion - `${XML//[<>]/ }` - it's essentially a poor man's sed, replacing `<>` with spaces in this case.  Then it just iterates with a for loop over what's left, which will be tags, close tags, and cdata.  Any slight change to the xml will break this.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) command-line toolkit for parsing and modifying XML.

For the above you can specify an XPath to pull out the text, respecting character encoding, entities etc.

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//name" x.xml
```

will give you the list of computer names (assuming your XML is in `x.xml`). You can format them more nicely thus:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m  "//name" -v "translate(.,'&#10;','')" -n x.xml
```

Comment: strictly, I'd like to use a BASH script to accomplish this if possible.

Comment: You might want to use a bash script, but you'll have to delegate to other utilities. e.g. in the above question you're delegating to sed. Note that sed isn't XML-aware, so it may work, but isn't a good solution long term

Comment: what do you recommend as the best solution? I need to get only the names from the above xml file so that I can run additional queries against those names

Comment: See above for a more comprehensive solution

Comment: Does anyone know how I can complete this request by using ONLY bash scripting commands?

Comment: You only have Bash to parse XML ? You should be in a very critical environment. Is it a scholar environment ? Above all, you are highly demanding for someone who has no reputation here.